# do_shortcode rendering section as black

Tags: php, wordpress

This code is working on my localhost running PHP 5.6.25 and Apache 2.4.23 to insert a section (rows and columns), created in the Divi builder (wordpress theme), into the website footer.

On my hosts server running PHP 5.6 (not sure which version of Apache but should be current) it's rendering a black area on the web page, instead of the proper graphics/colors/links/etc. The code is showing as properly inserted when viewing source.

Here's the code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="207988"][/et_pb_section]'); ?>
```

The section I'm trying to insert is good as it renders on a page contaent area fine.

I've been trying to troubleshoot this but no luck yet.

Is there an alternative or better way to code this?

Would the PHP cause this or could it be my host's configuration/set-up? I thought I'd start with the code first.

I can provide any missing details. Thanks for any help,
Gord

Comment: There's not alot of information here in terms of exactly where the PHP code is located. You said in the page content area but AFAIK you can't have PHP code in the page/post editor. Besides that, this shouldn't be a server configuration problem. My best guess is you're trying to render the shortcode before it's been loaded. It should be rendered during or after the [after_setup_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) action is fired.

Comment: I'm using a child theme and the PHP is located in the footer.php file.

Comment: It's a child theme and the PHP is located in the footer.php file.

I created the section in the Divi Library using the Divi builder. I added the section to a page using the Divi builder (not with PHP) to test it and see if there was an issue with the section itself. It rendered fine.

Does that help clarify things better?

This method was originally from here : https://quiroz.co/replace-the-default-footer-with-a-divi-builder-footer-saved-in-your-divi-library/

The last image in this tutorial shows the location of the PHP code in the footer.php file.

Thanks for any help,
Gord

Comment: As @ub3rst4r says, that's not a lot to go on. Please review  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Have you tried debugging the code in your shortcode to see 1. if its being called, 2. if the desired output it being created and 3. that it is being added correctly to your page?